# Getting all the pictures uploaded at once from the mongodb

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I stored a binary image in mongodb using the express js templating engine. My goal is to display all existing images in mongodb at once. When I have executed (/ picture) only one image is displayed. Please help me to display all the images from the Database. Thank you in advance :)

I have stored an image to my mongodb collection, and it looks something like this:
[image]

My router looks like:

```js
express = require('express')
   , router = express.Router()
   , MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
   , ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId
   , fs = require('fs-extra')
   // Your mongodb or mLabs connection string
   , url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
   , dbname= 'coffee_Image'
   , multer = require('multer')
   , util = require('util')
   , upload = multer({limits: {fileSize: 2000000 },dest:'/uploads/'}) 
// Default route http://localhost:3000/
router.get('/', function(req, res){ res.render('index'); });
// Form POST action handler
router.post('/uploadpicture', upload.single('picture'), function (req, res){ 
if (req.file == null) {
   // If Submit was accidentally clicked with no file selected...
  res.render('index', { title:'Please select a picture file to submit!'});
} else { 
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
   const db = client.db(dbname);
   // read the img file from tmp in-memory location
   var newImg = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
   // encode the file as a base64 string.
   var encImg = newImg.toString('base64');
   // define your new document
   var newItem = {
      description: req.body.description,
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      size: req.file.size,
      img: Buffer(encImg, 'base64')
   };
db.collection('CoffeeImg')
   .insert(newItem, function(err, result){
   if (err) { console.log(err); };
      var newoid = new ObjectId(result.ops[0]._id);
      fs.remove(req.file.path, function(err) {
         if (err) { console.log(err) };
         res.render('index', {title:'Thanks for the Picture!'});
         });
      });
   });
   };
});

router.get('/picture', function(req, res){
var filename = req.params.picture;
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
   const db = client.db(dbname);
   db.collection('CoffeeImg').find({filename}).toArray(function(err, results){
 if(err) throw err;
 results.forEach(function(result) {
        res.end(result.img.buffer);
 });
      });
   });
});

router.get('/AllPicture', function(req, res){
var filename = req.params.picture;
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
   const db = client.db(dbname);
   db.collection('CoffeeImg').find({filename}).toArray(function(err, results){
 if(err) throw err;
 res.json(results);
      });
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

html file looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
 <form action="/uploadpicture" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="picture" accept="application/x-zip-compressed,image/*">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description or Message">
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i enter localhost:3000/picture, i get only the first image:

[image: image2]

Comment: im not sure if I somehow missed it or not, but I think you are missing 'var' in your first line

Comment: and second, why are u using req.params.picture because I dont see any values in your URL parameter ?